# SQL Server: edit how the query result is displayed in the email sent by the SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have set up a stored procedure that will send an email if a condition is met and when the email is sent, it looks like this.

```
Name            Assignment
                                         Start_Date      End_Date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
---------------------------------------------------------------
Doe, John        Light Duty
                                            2019-01-05      2019-10-05
(1 row affected)
```

I want the headers to show in the same line, reduce the dotted lines and the result to show in the same line. How can I modify the query result display?

Comment: You can build a html body string with the query result, and specify @body_format = N'HTML' in the sp_send_dbmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Data') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Data

-- Create your dataset, assuming Name, Assignment, StartDate and EndDate as columns
SELECT
    *
INTO #Data
FROM YourTable

-- Variables to iterate into
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Assignment VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE

-- If dataset is empty, do nothing
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Data) > 0 BEGIN

    -- Create headers and css
    SET @HtmlContent = '
        <style>
            html { font-family:Arial }
            th, td { padding:5px; }
            table { border-collapse:collapse }
            th { background-color: blue; border:1px solid white }
            td { border: 1px solid #ccc }
        </style>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Assignment</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
            </tr>'

    -- Create and open cursor
    DECLARE DataCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM #Data
    OPEN DataCursor

    -- fetch first results
    FETCH NEXT FROM DataCursor INTO @Name, @Assignment, @StartDate, @EndDate

    -- Loop while results are still being fetched
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        -- Create the next html row
        SET @HtmlContent = @HtmlContent + '
            <tr>
                <td>' + @Name + '</td>
                <td>' + @Assignment + '</td>
                <td style=''text-align:center''>' + FORMAT(@StartDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') + '</td>
                <td style=''text-align:center''>' + FORMAT(@EndDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') + '</td>
            </tr>'

        -- Fetch the next results and restart loop
        FETCH NEXT FROM DataCursor INTO @Name, @Assignment, @StartDate, @EndDate
    END

    -- Close and cleanup the cursor
    CLOSE DataCursor
    DEALLOCATE DataCursor

    -- Close the table, we opened it in the headers
    SET @HtmlContent = @HtmlContent + '</table>'

    -- Send the stuff
    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Your mail profile',
        @recipients='Something@somewhere.com',
        @copy_recipients='Something@somewhere.com',
        @subject='My subject',
        @body=@HtmlContent,
        @body_format = 'HTML'
END
```

Bit gorilla and you should probably use nvarchars instead of varchars (There probably is no probably about that). But this might get you started. All you really need to do if change the "SELECT * INTO #Data FROM YourTable" to be from your actual table.

Edit: oh you'll need to change the details in the email bit right at the bottom too